# Read data from MS SQL server Database in rails ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I want to ***read data from MS SQL server***
and perform some operations and store it in my mysql database (two databases are involved here one is external for which i only have **read access**);
I have established the connection with MS SQL server with tinytds and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter , but when i run User.first or User.find command on console its **returning empty object( #< machinerawpunch > )**

And i m establishing connection in my model class. I created 2 different models one is for MS SQL table and other is my rails mysql which is normal.
My model class is here

```
class MachineRawPunch < ActiveRecord::Base
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection :savior721
  self.table_name = 'machinerawpunch'
end
```

My database.yml file is

```
 savior721:
   adapter: sqlserver
   mode : dblib
   dataserver: 192.68.1.2\SQLEXPRESS
   database: savior721
   username: user
   password: user

default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: assigment_app_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: assigment_app_test
```

Please help me find the right way to access SQL server.That is i dnt want an empty array of object i need data which i can manupulate.A way which would return some thing like this
    ***#***

Comment: how are you establishing the connection ?  are you running RAILS_ENV=savior721  or something similar?, and where do you want to establish the connection, in your app? in rake task ? at the console?    Does your SQL Server have a users table the follows rails conventions?

Comment: can you show the rails / dev logs of the queries being created when you query the sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay guys thanks for answering, and sorry for addressing this late;
but the bug was with gem `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` it wasn't working well with rails 4.
after switching to rails 3.2, all was working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The way I normally do this is to synchronize data in a rake task.

so for example  in `lib/tasks/import_legacy.rb`

```
namespace :admin do
   def connect_legacy_db
    require 'tiny_tds'
    config = Rails.configuration.database_configuration['legacy']
    TinyTds::Client.new :host=>config['host'], :username=>config['username'], :password=>config['password'], :database=>config['database']
  end

 desc "import all users from existing legacy db"
 task :import_all_users => [:environment ] do
    start=Time.now
    puts "Starting  user import at #{start}"
    client = connect_legacy_db
    # then my queries / transforms here such as
    query="EXEC sp_user_migration;"
    res = client.execute query
    res.each do |row|
        User.create name: row['username'] 
    end
  end
end
```

and my database.yml has the config for the legacy in there.    I pulled the connect_legacy_db  out to a method since it gets called from most of the tasks in there to sync various things over to the rails app.  My existing database doesn't come close to rails conventions, it was easier to just write stored procs to handle the data migration tasks, and use TinyTDS directly as opposed to the activerecord-sqlserver-adapter stuff.

Comment: Cannot use stored procedure i have read only access to database.

Comment: You don't have to use Stored Procs, I was just showing how I did it, you can easily write `query="Select * from users;"` or any other valid query, to get your data back,  as your question doesn't show the intended usage of the data I was showing one method of doing it..

Comment: just want normal query result something like #<MachineRawPunch id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> ;